# Do Peredhil lose their pointed ears when they choose to be counted as Edain?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, elves

Reading [Do Tolkien's Elves have pointy ears?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35059/do-tolkiens-elves-have-pointy-ears) got me thinking:

*Elrond* and *Elros* were born *Peredhil*, and given the choice whether to belong to the *Eldar* or the *Edain*.

In choosing, does their physical appearance change accordingly? In other words: did *Elros* or *Arwen* keep their pointy ears?

Or are *Peredhil* an exception and don't have pointy ears in the first place? (which would make all depictions of *Elrond* and *Arwen* I have ever seen faulty.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tolkien doesn't seem to have regarded pointed ears as being a specifically Elvish trait. After all, Hobbits have them, and they are explicitly described as more closely related to Men than to Elves. So it wouldn't necessarily be contradictory for Elros to be Edain and still have pointed ears.

Comment: Where are we told that hobbits have pointy ears?

Comment: In Letter 27: Tolkien says Hobbits have "a round, jovial face; [with] ears only slightly pointed and ‘elvish.’"